# RegisterDeviceNotification fails with error code 13

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-services

I'm trying to register for device notifications in for detecting USB flash drives in Windows. Below is my code part:

```
ZeroMemory( &NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter) );
NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
//NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USBSTOR;
HDEVNOTIFY hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(
        &serviceStatusHandle,
        &NotificationFilter,
DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE);
```

I'm trying to register with my service status handle, since this code is run in a service. hDevNotify returns NULL and `getLastError()` returns 13(INVALID_DATA) after that.

I am trying this code on a Windows XP machine.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is it correct to comment out the line `NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USBSTOR` ? Surely this will result in a zero GUID.

Comment: I also tried it without commenting out. No difference, same error code.

Comment: Surely the first parameter is wrong.  You want the handle itself, not a pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I needed to cast my handle to `HANDLE` explicitly though.